# Linear Programming Model with Strict Inequality and Negative Constraint

Tags: inequality, linear-programming, mathematical-modeling

I just want to know if it is possible to convert this LP model into a standard LP model:
$\max Z = 2x_1+4x_2$

subject to

$-2x_1+3x_2<3$

$4x_1+5x_2>10$

$x_1 \leq 0$

$x_1<4$

$x_2$ unbounded

This is my first time seeing an LP model with strict inequalities and a negative constraint. I just always see the LP model with the usual inequalities and non-negative constraint and of course, I know how to convert those LP models into standard LP models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace $-2x_1+3x_2<3$ by
$$
-2x_1+3x_2 \le 3-\varepsilon
$$
where $\varepsilon$ is a "very small" constant. And likewise for the other constraints.

Comment: Can I just use $\varepsilon$ for all the other constraints? Also, what about $x_1 \leq 0$?

Comment: yes you can use the same $\varepsilon$ for the other constraints. For $x_1\le 0$, define $\hat{x}_1 = - x_1$, rewrite the constraints in terms of $\hat{x}_1$, and impose $\hat{x}_1 \ge 0$.